# Github API returns different limit via curl and via browser

Tags: php, curl, github-api

I have a php script running on a remote server. The script curls the following URL

```
https://api.github.com/rate_limit?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXX
```

Which returns:

```
{"resources":{"core":{"limit":5000,"remaining":0,"reset":1392070288},"search":{"limit":30,"remaining":30,"reset":1392068042}},"rate":{"limit":5000,"remaining":0,"reset":1392070288}}
```

However, If I grab the same URL and put it in my browser I get

```
 {"resources": {"core": {"limit": 5000, "remaining": 5000, "reset": 1392071456 }, "search": { "limit": 30, "remaining": 30, "reset": 1392067916 } }, "rate": { "limit": 5000, "remaining": 5000, "reset": 1392071456 } }
```

Note that the "remaining" entry went from 0 to 5000. Any idea why this might happen? I think the latter is correct since there should be no reason I'm out of api calls.

Comment: I ended up killing my old application and starting a new one, with a different `client_id` and `client_secret`. That seems to have solved the problem, but I wouldn't reallly call it a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The API checks the User-Agent string. They use that to calculate (to a degree) and your IP address how many requests to the core resources you have remaining. The reset value in the result of that request tells you when (in seconds since the Epoch) you will be able to start requesting more resources. You should be able to check that value against a value you generate in your script.